# Best way to insert image over text?

Tags: html, css

i was wondering what the best way is to insert an image over text like this is? https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBXYG.png
Should i just float the top part of the text to both. The bottom image to the left and the bottom text to the right or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, image is inline element. And you just float the image to any part (right/left) then assign appropriate margin to make it clean from text.

```css
p img {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' <img src="http://www.modernartframing.com.au/images/video-icon.jpg" alt="img"/> will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
```

Comment: Thankyou, i got it to work with your code but not with lists - http://i.imgur.com/HQWUfLZ.png . I was going to paste the code but it's too big to put here so i can put it on pastebin or something if you need a look at the code. But technically you shouldn't need the code since the list is already inside the p tag and is given no id/class.